# Magento2: Lock wait timeout exceeded - catalog_product_entity - loading products

Tags: magento2, database, products, indexing, timeout

I am experiencing locks on the **`catalog_product_entity`** table when uploading a lot of products in a short period.

**Error:**

> SQLSTATE[HY000]:General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout
>   exceeded; try restarting transaction. query was: 
>   `UPDATE catalot_product_entity SET row_id=?` ...etc

We've traced it back to a previous job running which updates a particular product, and then another job with the same product runs at the same time that scheduled indexing is running (and obviously refreshing indexes for previous load - It looks like the indexer might lock a series of rows while updating, haven't looked in to how it works).

I've confirmed that products that are in the current job have been recently updated in a previous job - although at times 10 minutes earlier.

Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this issue, or anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to restart the mysql server? have experienced this "Lock wait timeout exceeded" few times before. and I have fixed them by simply restarting the mysql server